# LINQ Join where the NULLS are returned Also

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to do a JOIN in a LINQ statement where it brings back the NULLS also. My code is:

```
var linqQuery = (from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
     join a in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on ((EntityReference)r["accountid"]).Id equals a["accountid"]
     join c in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"]
     where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(new Guid("c55c2e09-a3be-e011-8b2e-00505691002b"))
     select new
     {
         OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
         CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
         Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
         ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name,
         Source = !r.Contains("new_source") ? string.Empty : r["new_source"],
         CreatedOn = !r.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : r["createdon"],
         State = !a.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : a["address1_stateorprovince"],
         Zip = !a.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? string.Empty : a["address1_postalcode"],
         Eval = !r.Contains("new_colderevaluation") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["new_colderevaluation"],
         DistributorName = !r.Contains("new_channelpartner") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Name,
         ContactStreetAddress = !c.Contains("address1_line1") ? string.Empty : c["address1_line1"]
     });
```

This pulls down the one record were contactid matches, but I also want it to bring down the records with a NULL contactid.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What is this - LINQ-to-SQL, LINQ-to-Entities, or LINQ-to-Objects?

Comment: So basically you want a right join on c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right outer joins are not supported in LINQ. Consider re-arranging your table sources so that you can do a left outer join using the DistinctIfEmpty extension method. Alternatively, you can use a LINQ version of SQL-Ansi82 instead of joins by writing all of the joins as where clauses.

Comment: Maybe he needs to invert the query, right join as the same a join.

Comment: Yes, inverting the query can turn a right join into a left one. Also, if you take advantage of associations rather than joins in your LINQ, you will get an outer join rather than inner by default.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. What do you mean by inverting the query?

Comment: Instead of doing Opportunity Right Join Account, try Account Left Join Opportunity